# Debian 10 production packages cannot be found

Tags: docker, debian

Hi I have an docker image and I noticed after yesterday I cannot run it as it run the error that some repository url is invalid. And when I check I saw that it is true the debian repository structure has already been change https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/ on 16/6/2021. Does any one know the solution?

```
FROM python:3.7-buster

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y \
    msodbcsql17 \
    unixodbc-dev \
    openssh-server \
    nginx-full \
    --no-install-recommends \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

error
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue with the Debian 9 repository, looks like all the `/pool/` folders are gone

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: The same Dockerfile works on my side currently...

Comment: @atline are you building the image from cache, I have to clean up the cache first or else it will build from cache and no error will be raised

Comment: @PhuongDuyenHuynhNgoc No, I never build related layer in the past, meanwhile `--no-cache` added.

Comment: During my build, it shows `Get:20 https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod buster/main amd64 libodbc1 amd64 2.3.7 [511 kB]`, looks not same as yours... Not sure what happened...

Comment: @atline that is really weird, i tried to run it many times but it always say that the ip is invalid

Comment: I confirm that the binaries are missing and no longer hosted on the  `packages.microsoft.com` repository for all the linux distributions

Comment: I guess I know why I works. `https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/` looks just a front cdn. I'm from Asia, it still show `08-Jul-2019 21:31`. That means some CDN node in Europe has issue, but CDN in Asia no issue... This is why it works on my side...

Comment: The issue has been reported over at dotnet core on github, the progress can be followed there https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6381

Answer (score 1):

It is a general issue, the issue is partially solved but the download speed is very slow. Here is a detailed report from bleepingcomputer blog post :[Microsoft Linux repos suffer day-long outage, still recovering](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/microsoft-linux-repos-suffer-day-long-outage-still-recovering/)

> Although Microsoft's initial ETA to resolve the issue was "two hours or so," the problem spanned well over 14 hours, with users continuing to experience degraded performance.

Microsoft engineer Rahul Bhandari stepped in on the same GitHub thread to confirm:

> "Our infra team is working on this. There is an issue with some of the mirrors on packages.microsoft.com so as per them, the current ETA to resolve this issue is in next two hours or so," said Bhandari.

> Bhandari later confirmed that some storage issues were the root cause of these problems.

Microsoft's principal engineering manager, Ravindra Bhartiya said:

> "We had an incident with packages.microsoft.com that resulted in packages being unavailable."

> "Our engineering team has mitigated the issue and our internal data shows improvement in the availability"

> "If you still have problems, please provide us more information (output of "apt-get update|install") and we can investigate it further," said Bhartiya.

> But even into today, at the time of writing, users are complaining about slow download speeds when retrieving packages from Microsoft's repo.