# Not able to install Microsoft ODBC driver in Docker

Tags: docker, unixodbc

I am trying to build a Docker image with the Microsoft ODBC driver installed following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#debian17). This used to work for me, but not anymore. I receive this error message:

> E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod/pool/main/u/unixodbc/libodbc1_2.3.7_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
> E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod/pool/main/u/unixodbc/odbcinst_2.3.7_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
> E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod/pool/main/u/unixodbc/odbcinst1debian2_2.3.7_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
> E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod/pool/main/u/unixodbc/unixodbc_2.3.7_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
> E: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql17/msodbcsql17_17.7.2.1-1_amd64.deb  404
> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
> The command '/bin/sh -c ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17' returned a non-zero code: 100

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.7

# Configure the MS SQL query drivers
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN apt update 
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
```

These links indeed do not lead anywhere. How to solve this?

Comment: Same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68014478/debian-10-production-packages-cannot-be-found
As mentioned in the comments, it looks like all the /pool/ folders are gone

Comment: I reported the missing pool folder to Microsoft here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/ and immediately received phishing emails in return